# Can I auto-update my Github after publishing from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github

Is there a way to automate storing code updates to GitHub after a developer publishes a new version of code from Visual Studio (2017 or 2019)?

Or is there a way to automate storing code updates to any code repository?

We also currently use VisualSVN, but are open to other repository software packages if they solve this problem for us.
We publish web projects and console apps to on-prem servers, so my understanding is that GitHub Actions won't work for us (yet).

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing to an on-premise Git repository hosting server, you can add to that remote repository a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks).

Said hook can in turn analyze what just got pushed and push it in turn to GitHub.

See [`git-post-receive-hook-push-to-mirrors`](https://github.com/mysociety/misc-scripts/blob/master/bin/git-post-receive-hook-push-to-mirrors) as an example of such hook.

Comment: Thanks! What if we're not pushing to a Git repository hosting server? Currently we're just publishing our code to a folder on our network.

Comment: @Melanie I would `git init` (initialize) a git bare repository in that folder (emptied of its content): that way, you can benefit from Git hooks when pushing to that bare repository.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm a git noob but I'll look into this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Melanie For a concrete example: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-git-hook-to-push-to-your-server-and-github-repo-fe51f59122dd